# How to use the bootstrap confirmation within the bootstrap modal box?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, confirmation, bootstrap-popover

I want to use the **bootstrap confirmation** http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#example within the **bootstrap modal box**.

However while calling the modal box I'm calling the modal box by ajax post method. And while calling the modal box I also include some scripts but its not working.

The scripts I have sent in the jquery is http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Clean-jQuery-Confirmation-Dialog-Plugin-with-Bootstrap-Popovers-Bootstrap-Confirmation.html

Used this script within the modal box window...

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation();
                $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
placement: 'top', // How to position the confirmation - top | bottom | left | right
trigger: 'click', // How confirmation is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual
target : '_self', // Default target value if `data-target` attribute isn't present.
href   : '#', // Default href value if `data-href` attribute isn't present.
title: 'Are you sure?', // Default title value if `data-title` attribute isn't present
template: '<div class="popover">' +
                '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
                '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' +
                '<div class="popover-content text-center">' +
                '<div class="btn-group">' +
                '<a class="btn btn-small" href="" target=""></a>' +
                '<a class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="confirmation"></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>',
btnOkClass:  'btn-primary', // Default btnOkClass value if `data-btnOkClass` attribute isn't present.
btnCancelClass:  '', // Default btnCancelClass value if `data-btnCancelClass` attribute isn't present.
btnOkLabel: '<i class="icon-ok-sign icon-white"></i> Yes', // Default btnOkLabel value if `data-btnOkLabel` attribute isn't present.
btnCancelLabel: '<i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> No', // Default btnCancelLabel value if `data-btnCancelLabel` attribute isn't present.
singleton: false, // Set true to allow only one confirmation to show at a time.
popout: false, // Set true to hide the confirmation when user clicks outside of it.
onConfirm: function(){}, // Set event when click at confirm button
onCancel: function(){}}) // Set event when click at cancel button

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please post your code. Without it we cannot help you too much.

Comment: I have to ask one more question. Have included correctly both libraries (bootstrap and bootstrap confirmation) ?

Comment: yes bootstrap confirmation and bootstrap modal box is included in the base page. and bootstrap modal box is working fine. and bootstrap confirmation box is working in the base page fine but its not working inside the modal box

Comment: I have add an answer. Did it help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modal is called by ajax you have to know that elements inside modal box are delegeted elements.

Look here at chapter **Direct and delegated events**
https://api.jquery.com/on/

Propably then you should use it like that:

```
$(document).find('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation();
```

This way you can access delegated elements added by javascript or in ajax actions.

Comment: I think by the Z-index value the popover is not displaying

Answer (score 2):

I've just made a demo for you. It may help you.
Please, check the following fiddle - http://bit.ly/1aD42Y8

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't put the url in correct format. I was getting error.

Comment: Misa Lazovic @ Thanks for your help.

Comment: No i dont want the normal bootstrap modalbox alert i want bootstrap confirmation

Comment: Instead of using a bootstrap modal box like this you can use the bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/)